# Array of Integer in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, int

I try to create an array like below:

```
count = [corners count]; 

Gluint indices [count];
```

i used the count value and it works fine but when creating array of indices the value is not there. It seems to have

```
indices [-1]
```

what should i do? the value of count is different based on the data of corners. I cannot used this code below:

```
Gluint indices [24];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
Gluint *indices = malloc(count * sizeof(Gluint));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use NSMutableData you then get things like reference counting if that is useful to you, it also makes it easier to change the size.